# setting crontab remotely using shell script.

Tags: bash, shell, echo, ksh

I am trying to write a code which will setup an crontab remotely using shell script. But I am facing issue with echo command as its not able to substitute variables.

## Actual Code

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh
#! /bin/bash
clear

echo -n "" > error.out
echo -n "" > scripts_dir.out
echo -n "" > crontab_check.out


export ORACLE_SID=REPTEST
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0_tipical
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export TNS_ADMIN=/home/oracle/NIKHIL/apex_oracle_version_changes
export SCRIPTS_DIR=/home/oracle/NIKHIL/Migration_tech_refersh
export REP_USER=repository
export EMAIL_ID="nikhil.mehta@neustar.biz"
export DAY=`date +"%m-%d-%Y"` 
export HOSTNAME=$1
export SID=$2
export USAGE=$3
export ROLE=$4


create_crontab_entries() {

    echo -n "" > ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/crontab_remote_entries/crontab_remote_file_${H_NOFQDN}.${SID}
    echo
    echo -e "Creating crontab entries for RMAN backups and alert_log script"
    echo
    mv ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/crontab_remote_entries/crontab_remote_file_${H_NOFQDN}.${SID} ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/crontab_remote_entries/crontab_remote_file_${H_NOFQDN}.${SID}_$DAY
    echo -e "(crontab -l 2>/dev/null;echo "0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /home/oracle/SCRIPTS/MONITOR/alert_log/ksh/CHECK_LOG_ERRORS.ksh ${SID} > /tmp/check_log_${SID}.log 2>&1") |  crontab - " >> ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/crontab_remote_entries/crontab_remote_file_${H_NOFQDN}.${SID}

    echo -e "Checking if crontab is enabled for oracle user"
    ssh -o 'PreferredAuthentications=publickey' oracle@${HOSTNAME} "crontab -l" >> crontab_check.out 2>&1

    if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
            echo
            echo -e "Crontab is enabled for Oracle user.. Creating Crontab entries!!!"
            scp  -o 'PreferredAuthentications=publickey' ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/crontab_remote_entries/crontab_remote_file_${H_NOFQDN}.${SID} oracle@${HOSTNAME}:/home/oracle >> crontab_check.out 2>&1
            ssh -o 'PreferredAuthentications=publickey' oracle@${HOSTNAME} "chmod 777 /home/oracle/crontab_remote_file_${H_NOFQDN}.${SID};/home/oracle/crontab_remote_file_${H_NOFQDN}.${SID};rm -f /home/oracle/crontab_remote_file_${H_NOFQDN}.${SID}" >> crontab_check.out 2>&1
```

## Problamatic echo Command

```
echo -e "(crontab -l 2>/dev/null;echo "0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /home/oracle/SCRIPTS/MONITOR/alert_log/ksh/CHECK_LOG_ERRORS.ksh ${SID} > /tmp/check_log_${SID}.log 2>&1") |  crontab - " >> ${SCRIPTS_DIR}/crontab_remote_entries/crontab_remote_file_${H_NOFQDN}.${SID}
```

## Errors encountered while running script

```
Migration_tech_refersh_post_check.ksh: line 275: 1) |  crontab - : ambiguous redirect
```

Please help with the echo command which will substitute variables as expected.

Comment: Try escaping the 2nd and 3rd `"` in your echo. `echo \"0,5,10` and `2>&1\")`

Comment: The syntax highlighting is your friend...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by separating the whole command into 3 strings as below.

```
    str1='(crontab -l 2>/dev/null;echo "0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /home/oracle/SCRIPTS/MONITOR/alert_log/ksh/CHECK_LOG_ERRORS.ksh '
    str2="$str1 $SID > /tmp/check_log_${SID}.log 2>&1"
    str3='") |  crontab - '
    full_cmd1="$str2$str3"
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Regards,
Lancerique.